# r time series to panel by group and month

Tags: r, dataframe, panel, time-series

So I have a dataframe with about 500,000 obs that looks like this:

```
ID    MonthYear    Group
123   200811       Blue
345   201102       Red
678   201110       Blue
910   201303       Green
```

I would like to convert this to a panel that counts the number of occurrences for each group in each month.  So it would look like this:

```
MonthYear    Group    Count
200801       Blue     521
200802                400
....
200801       Red      521
200802                600
....
```

I guess it doesn't need to look exactly like that, but just some way to turn this into a useful panel.  Aggregate doesn't seem to be sufficient in and of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(dfrm$ID, dfrm[,c("MonthYear","Group")], length)
```

If you want to reverse the grouping just reverse the order of the INDEX argument.

Comment: Or in formula style: `aggregate(ID~ MonthYear + Group, length, data=dfrm)`

Comment: Ah perfect!  I guess I was on the right track with aggregate(0 just couldn;t get it to work right.  Thanks.

Comment: You could have used `tapply` to get the same information but it would have been in wide-format.